# Sorting messages for different users from database

Tags: spring, hibernate, postgresql, spring-mvc

I am working in a Spring-MVC application with Hibernate and Postgres. In the application I am adding chat functionality. I am using a very simple database schema for saving chats. In the schema, for the table Messages, there are 2 foreign keys, referred to table User as sender and receiver. 
I am currently able to send and receive messages, but the problem is I want to club the messages into conversations between users. I have timestamp to sort the messages by time, but I don't know how to group them by the other user(reciever name) and display them in the front end(HTML)

I am posting some of the code and schema, kindly have a look :

SQL code :

```
CREATE TABLE public.userinfo (
                id INTEGER NOT NULL,
                email VARCHAR,
                username VARCHAR,
                displayname VARCHAR,
                password VARCHAR,
                CONSTRAINT id PRIMARY KEY (id)
);


CREATE TABLE public.conversation (
                conversation_id NUMERIC NOT NULL,
                messagetext VARCHAR,
                time DATE,
                id INTEGER NOT NULL,
                userinfo_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
                CONSTRAINT conversation_id PRIMARY KEY (conversation_id)
);



ALTER TABLE public.conversation ADD CONSTRAINT userinfo_conversation_fk
FOREIGN KEY (id)
REFERENCES public.userinfo (id)
ON DELETE NO ACTION
ON UPDATE NO ACTION
NOT DEFERRABLE;

ALTER TABLE public.conversation ADD CONSTRAINT userinfo_conversation_fk1
FOREIGN KEY (userinfo_id)
REFERENCES public.userinfo (id)
ON DELETE NO ACTION
ON UPDATE NO ACTION
NOT DEFERRABLE;
```

MessagesDAOImple :

```
@Override
    public boolean addMessage(User sender, User receiver, Messages messages) {
        if( session == null) {
            session = this.sessionFactory.openSession();
        }else {
            session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        }
        int id = sender.getId();
        User sender1 = (User) session.get(User.class,id);
        sender.getMessages1().add(messages);
        receiver.getMessages2().add(messages);
        session.saveOrUpdate(messages);
        session.flush();
        return true;
    }

@Override
    public List<Messages> listMessagesForUser(User user) {
        if(session == null){
            session = this.sessionFactory.openSession();
        } else{
            session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        }
        int id = user.getId();
        Query query = session.createQuery("from Messages as m where m.user2.id=:id");
        query.setParameter("id",id);
        List<Messages> messagesList= query.list();
        return messagesList;

    }
```

I am still writing the html code, so I don't have it right now, but if there is a possibility of using something easy like c:forEach and displaying the messages as list for testing grouped by conversations is what I am looking for. Any pointers or suggestions would be nice. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're looking for.

Here is some SQL to return a conversation between two users (123 & 321)

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT * from conversation WHERE id = 123 and user_info_id = 321
    UNION 
    SELECT * from conversation WHERE id = 321 and user_info_id = 123
) conv ORDER BY time ASC
```

Here is a query to get all conversations for a user 123 & and any partner

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT user_info_id AS partner_id, * from conversation WHERE id = 123
    UNION 
    SELECT id AS partner_id, * from conversation WHERE user_info_id = 123
) conv ORDER BY partner_id, time ASC
```

Using the above will require you to loop thru the results and decide to display the different conversation partners via partner_id.

To avoid the loop, you might want to consider a aggregate function, but i'm not sure of the performance of the GROUP BY clause here.

```
SELECT partner_id, array_agg(messagetext) FROM (
    SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT user_info_id AS partner_id, * from conversation WHERE id = 123
        UNION 
        SELECT id AS partner_id, * from conversation WHERE user_info_id = 123
    ) conv ORDER BY time ASC
) conv_aggs GROUP BY partner_id
```

protip.. you may want array_to_json(array_agg(messagetext))

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. What I am trying to do is get conversation between 2 users and display them as conversations between users like how facebook does. Left side, you see conversations, and when opened, the conversation between the 2 users. How to do that with the schema I have posted is what I want to know.

Comment: I guess then I have to maintain somewhere which all conversation a user has, and then retrieve them.

Comment: You can retrieve all the conversations a user has via the second query... just return DISTINCT partner_id instead of *